# How to resolve static don't found on hosting django

Tags: python, django

Django does not load static on a site that is hosted (collectstatic did).I know that there are a lot of such questions, but I tried most of the solutions and did not help(I do not know what files to expose to understand the problem, so if you need more, I will expose)

settings.py(static part):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')


MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (

    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
     '/home/users/m/marselabdullin/caparol_center_spb_decision/static/',

)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

static folder on hosting:
[image]

Comment: In a production setup you have to serve `static` and `media` separately by your webserver.

Comment: Please can you tell about it in more detail(its my first attempt to deploy site)

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how your webhoster is managed.

Comment: I just thought you meant something like nginx

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/

Comment: Whether you're using apache or nginx, you need to configure your server where to find the static files for location `/static/`. Django does not serve static files in production. [Here's an example for apache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: thanks, that's what i meant